# How can i write information words into a file with c++

Tags: c++

Am trying to Write file into a file but once i enter the name it prompts a click to close

this is mine code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void login(){
    char name, email, address;

  ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open ("user.dll");
    cout << "Enter Name :  ";
    cin >> name;
    cout << "Enter Email : ";
    cin >> email;
    cout << "Enter Address : ";
    cin >> address;
    myfile <<name << email << address << endl;

}
int main()
{
    login();
    system("pause");
    return(0);
}
```

and the is the display 
[image: diaplay]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be entering `std::string`s not `char`s. Change

```
char name, email, address;
```

To

```
string name, email, address;
```

**Why did it seemingly skip your 2nd and 3rd `cin` prompts?**

You used `std::cin` to read the input from the stream. During the first prompt, you entered `"chrys"`, which added 5 `char`s to the stream.

If you followed the operations of `cin` you basically had:

```
name = 'c'
email = 'h'
address = 'r'
```

If you would have used `getch()` for example, this would have been obvious. If you were set on `char` you would have had to use the C-like method of reading into a `char[]`, but since this is C++, `std::string` is a much better option for your case.

Comment: And you'll probably want to use [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) instead of operator `>>` if `name` and `address` may contain spaces.

Comment: ya. let string do the heavy lifting. Or you could try char name[80] and then play with buffers and pointers, but why?

Comment: @user1269942 Please don't give them any ideas :) next thing you know we'll have `char*` questions popping up left and right!

Comment: Working now but all input are placed in the same line is there a way to make each one go to a new line?

Comment: @ChrysUgwu `endl` is your friend.

Comment: Sorry Am a Serious NOOB were do i add it

Comment: After each `getline`, you would `cout << endl;`

Comment: Tutorial!  Chrys, I commend you for taking on C++. It's a serious language and it's a hard learning curve. There are some really good tutorials out there.  Maybe try: http://www.programmr.com/zone/cpp Good luck!

Comment: For an upvote, actually explain why reading into a `char` meant all the input operations had enough data to go on until after the program's natural end, without new lines being provided.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I thought for sure this had to have a well-written duplicate post on Stack Overflow somewhere but couldn't find one. Hopefully I didn't gloss over too much.